# Alternative for commons-logging-1.2.jar to be added in pom.xml file for Log4j to avoid org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite, apache-commons-logging

Alternative for commons-logging-1.2.jar to be added in pom.xml file for Log4j logging Framework to avoid below error from displaying:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

After following some priliminary solving steps by adding commons-logging-1.2.jar file in the /WEB-INF/lib/ folder and also tried to add commons-logging-1.2 dependency in the pom.xml file, still didn't fetch any good results.

These are the Log4j.properties details:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Appender1, Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=D:/Logs/SpringMVC.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

This is pom.xml file dependencies included:

```
<log4j.version>1.6.5</log4j.version>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>  
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for answer over website, this weblink focused some light on the solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688114/5984671

And here are the changes made to pom.xml file, after which it executed without error:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j13</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.log4j13.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>

<!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency> -->
```

(Short Note: 
Will there be any clash if I use both slf4j-api and log4j-api dependency, any comment on this is appreciable)